# How to have sudo show the command in the password prompt?

Tags: linux, security, sudo

Is it possible to have the sudo prompt to also show the command?

the simple `[SUDO] password` is fine if you were the one to invoke it. But often you run a script and would like to double check what you are agreeing to. I already leave timeout set to zero so i have to confirm each time.

I would love to have something like

```
[SUDO] PWD: /home/user/
[SUDO] CMD: /bin/ls -la *.c
[SUDO] password: _
```

Comment: All of the available options for configuring `sudo` are described in the `sudo` and `sudoers` man pages. If there's nothing suitable there, the answer is probably "no" (or possibly, "wrap `sudo` with a custom command").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### About `*.c`

First of all, it would be quite tricky to make `sudo` (or any supporting contraption) print `/bin/ls -la *.c`, because when you run

```
sudo /bin/ls -la *.c
```

in a shell, it's the shell that expands `*.c` before it starts `sudo`. `sudo` gets the *result* of the expansion and it has no way to know `*.c` was ever there.

I guess with [magic alias](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/aliases.html) and the shell history one can do something about it, but:

- Your concern is `sudo` in a script. The interpreter for the script may be a shell that doesn't support history; and even if it does, it probably won't do this while interpreting a script; and even if it would, it probably wouldn't use the alias by default.
- If I were you, I would want to see the *actual* command that gets to `sudo`, e.g. `/bin/ls -la bar.c baz.c foo.c`. A better example is to imagine the script calls `sudo "$tool" "$arg1" "$arg2"`; do you want to see exactly this? or the expanded *actual* command?

Now I assume you don't necessarily need to see `*.c`, you accept seeing whatever `*.c` expanded to.

---

#### Wrapper

You can build a custom `sudo` that prints what you want and calls the real `sudo`. A relatively simple wrapper script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printf '[SUDO] PWD: %s\n' "$PWD" >/dev/tty
printf '[SUDO] CMD: ' >/dev/tty
printf '%s ' sudo "${@@Q}" >/dev/tty
printf '\n' >/dev/tty
exec /usr/bin/sudo "$@"
```

If you name the script `sudo`, make it executable and place it in a directory that's in your `$PATH` before `/usr/bin` (note I assume your real `sudo` is `/usr/bin/sudo`, so does the wrapper), then whenever you will call `sudo`, you will call the wrapper. It will (unconditionally) print the information you want before executing the real `sudo`.

Notes:

- It's easy to set this up for a single user, i.e. without affecting other users: the wrapper in a private `bin` directory, `$PATH` modified accordingly. It's possible to set this up for all sudoers (but I won't elaborate).
- The wrapper prints to `/dev/tty`. It's a good idea (imagine `sudo foo >result 2>log`, you don't want to litter the `result` or `log`). Your real `sudo` most likely prints its prompt to the tty as well.
- The wrapper prints something like `[SUDO] CMD: sudo ls …` rather than `[SUDO] CMD: ls …` you wanted. This is by design. Imagine the command was `sudo -E ls …`, `[SUDO] CMD: -E ls …` looks weird. Parsing the arguments only to omit `-E` in the output is a useless effort; or even harmful, don't you want to know `-E` was used? `[SUDO] CMD: sudo -E ls …` is fine.
- The interpreter is `bash`, not `sh`, because I chose to use `@Q` to print the arguments as quoted to avoid ambiguity. Alternatively it may be `printf '%q ' sudo "$@" >/dev/tty`. The two variants may give different (yet equivalent) output, so choose whichever you like better.
- A script may change `$PATH` for itself; or it can call the real `sudo` by its full path. So it's possible it will circumvent the wrapper.
- The real `sudo` is smart enough to wait for another `sudo` using the same terminal. In other words: two `sudo`s in `sudo foo | sudo bar` won't ask you for your password in parallel. Our wrapper is not that smart, two wrappers started in parallel can print in parallel.

The wrapper is not a perfect solution.

---

#### PAM

If your `sudo` uses [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM), it's possible to make it execute a script before it asks for your password.

Read to the end before you attempt to do anything.

Note: almost everything we're going to do in this section requires `sudo` or an elevated shell (`sudo -i`). You should start at least one elevated shell and keep it running until after all the changes you make sure (as a normal user) your `sudo` still works. The shell will be a lifesaver if you (we) manage to break your `sudo` somehow.

Save the following code as `/usr/local/bin/sudo_pam_script` and make the file executable. The file should belong to `root:root` and its mode should be `rwxr-xr-x`. This is the code:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printf '[SUDO] PWD: %s\n' "$PWD"
printf '[SUDO] CMD: '
</proc/"$PPID"/cmdline mapfile -d '' arg
printf '%q ' "${arg[@]}"
exit 0
```

Edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and add the following line before all uncommented lines:

```
auth    optional    pam_exec.so stdout /usr/local/bin/sudo_pam_script
```

From now on your `sudo` will run the script if it's going to ask for a password. It won't do this if it's not going to ask though.

Notes:

- This solution is global, it affects all sudoers, they cannot easily opt out.
- I know little about your OS. You tagged [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), so `/proc` is probably there (but in general it doesn't have to). Your `sudo` may or may not use PAM, or its configuration may interfere. I tested the solution in Kubuntu.
- `>/dev/tty` is not required. `sudo` itself should redirect (or rather relay) the output of the script.
- Instead of `printf '%q ' "${arg[@]}"` you can use `printf '%s ' "${arg[@]@Q}"`. Try both and pick one.
- This solution is better than the wrapper when it comes to `sudo foo | sudo bar`. Still you won't see the whole pipeline as one command, because each `sudo` knows its own part only.
- In my Kubuntu the solution does not apply to `sudo -i`. There's a separate file `/etc/pam.d/sudo-i` that is relevant to this case.

Comment: Thank you! and actually showing the expanded glob patterns is a benefit

Comment: only change i made: `printf '%s \n' "${arg[@]}" | tr '\n' ' '` ...not sure i need the escaping of %q, and <$@ add \n between the params...

Comment: and a note for the next person, if you add this in pam.d after the common auth stuff, you will get the information /after/ the password prompt. Obviously this have to be earlier in the list.

Comment: As an aside, the one command where I've found this kind of technique useful is `rm`, to avoid deleting too many files when using a glob pattern.  For that I use an alias for `rm` that shows me the list of files when that list is longer than a single item.  That seems to be the most common case for me, to use a glob pattern intending to match a single file, where I want to protect against that pattern accidentally matching multiple files.  I use this alias instead of some kind of "undo" for `rm`.  This doesn't really have anything to do with `sudo` however.